# Laravel API Post Returns Login Screen

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two resource routes that both call the store method on my model.

```
Route::resource(/calls, 'CallController'); <--- Inside routes/web.php
Route::resource(/v1/calls, 'CallController'); <--- Inside routes/api.php
```

When I post to https://example.com/calls, the model is correctly persisted to the database and the appropriate response is returned.

When I post to https://example.com/api/v1/calls, I get a 201 response and the login screen is returned.

Why am I getting two different responses? At first I thought it might be the CRSF token, but I am using Laravel 5.6. As far as I know, neither of these routes are behind any authentication.

I have attached the request headers of the successful call not using the API

```
:authority: example.com
:method: POST
:path: /calls
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 214
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IkZlRzFxSERKbVplWFNrdEhaSUJyN3c9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiaHRab3o4b2Q3d3h4WVNFNnRUYmw2Qm5yN0gwczJ6eDR6aFFIXC9wNmVvTzFvckE2Wks5djRjcjJDTkttRDd6VHB4V1IzK3Z4RldTZkF4Vkl2WlNLdmpBPT0iLCJtYWMiOiJiYTJlZjY1ZWM4MWNjYmIyZjllMTMyNjkzMWY5YzU1YzhlMDUxMjU0MmI0YWQ5ZDMyZmQ3ZjZiY2NlZjA5MDQ5In0%3D; test_session=eyJpdiI6ImgwbG1wd0U2N3gxN1djNURCY3JNdUE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYWF1c3JJXC9MZ0ZJVjhoSDNQS0ZtbGlGXC91UkZXeEZOenE2MVJTQXlUZFFwZVlPUHNKS3pieEtmc2hFM3EzNnB6SFVLVHZUQVlGTEdub1wvaXBhVmhncHc9PSIsIm1hYyI6ImQzOGYwMWIxZGM2ODM1NjZhYjAyMjdiNGM4YjI2NDA3NTY3YzVlNzc3YWMyNjIwOTY3YTlkNTY0YWI0YTk3MTkifQ%3D%3D
origin: https://example.com
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://example.com/web
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.84 Safari/537.36
x-csrf-token: OyGKA35SMQJINoANVje94osmQOSNQAZT7MCx4LQA
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
```

Comment: Can you add your `CallController@store` method? How are you making your `POST` request (API)?

Comment: How are you posting to the API? You may need to set `Content-Type: application/json` headers.

Comment: Are the routes you are expecting listed when you execute `artisan route:list` ?

Comment: @Aknosis I can confirm that the route is listed when I run artisan route:list. I added CallController@store, I got the same problem. I am currently trying to make the call using Postman (Chrome). I tried Content-Type: application/json and Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add the following header to your API request:

```
Accept: application/json       // <-- this indicates how you'd like to receive the response
/** and optionally: */
Content-type: application/json // <-- this indicates the data format that you are sending
```

This will tell Laravel to use the `api` guard, because by default Laravel uses the `web` one.

Comment: Nailed it! Thank you!